# get values of multiple input boxes inside a div of each div with $(selector).each

Tags: jquery, dictionary, each

I have a select list with products on clicking an add button you it will generate the info and display it inside input boxes that are inside a div that has an id, each time you add a product a new div is added, on registering all products I want to get the info of the input boxes for each div that is created here's the code:
This is the one that makes the div's and inputs

```
$(document).on('click', '#ap', function() {
    var desctext =  $('#descripcion option:selected').text();
    var descval = $('#descripcion option:selected').val();
    var html = 
        '<div class="productoaline">' +
        '<input type="text" class="id" name="descval" readonly="readonly" value="' + descval + '"/>' +
        '<input type="text" class="text" readonly="readonly" value="' + desctext + '"/>' +
        '<input type="text" class="text" name="cantidad" placeholder="CANTIDAD DESEADA" value=""/>' +
        '<input type="button" class="button remove" value="Quitar" />' +
        '<div>';
    $('#productosa').append(html);
});
```

This is the one to get values that I have so far

```
$(document).on('click', '#registrar', function(){
//var idp;
var cant;

// $('.productoaline').each(function(index){

$('.productoaline').each(function(index){
    //idp = $('name=["descval"]').val();
    cant = $('name=["cantidad"]').val();
    alert(index + ':' + cant);
 });

 // });

});
```

I only need the ones that have names how can I get only those inputs from each div. how about selecting the even index it appears that the even index are the one that I need.
Thank's for the help! I've thought of using map but I have never used it any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Step 1: Don't create duplicate ids. At the moment each time you add a div and its inputs they have the same id as the ones that went before. I'd expect `$('#productoaline').each()` to iterate over whichever element was created first and ignore the rest. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things to note here...

- You're only supposed to use a certain `id` once in a document, if you're using it more than once, you might want to consider using a class, or try iterating the id: "productoaline1", "productoaline2", etc...
- Inside of your each loop you're selecting `#cantidad`, which will naturally only give you a result the third time.
- You should be using `console.log()` instead of `alert()` to display debug information. This will output information to your browser's console. You access the console via something like Firefox's Firebug, or Google Chrome's Inspector.

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
$('#productoaline > input').each( function( index ){
    console.log( index, $(this).val() );
});
```

Comment: Yes it's something like that only problem is that I don't want the values of the second and last input (last input value is the name of the button) I only need the id and "#cantidad" I gave them id's to get the values of the selected input's only but I guess that was wrong so how can I do that? Should I give them names instead of id's? how about selecting the even index it appears that the even index are the one that I need